# Django: creating form with unknown amount of select input

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

i have form in my template that works well but i want to "convert" this form to django form. In my class register i have form with unknown amount of selects because in one class i can have 12 students in other 18.
Here is my code:

html

```
<form method="post">
                      {% csrf_token %}
                      <table class="table">
                          <thead>
                              <tr>
                                  <th>ID</th>
                                  <th>first name</th>
                                  <th>last name</th>
                                  <th>January</th>
                                  <th>February</th>
                                  <th>March</th>
                                  <th>April</th>
                              </tr>
                          </thead>
                          
                            
                            {% for student in students %}
                            <tbody>
                                <!-- Grades -->
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{ student.id }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ student.student.first_name }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ student.student.last_name }}</td>
                                    <td>
                                      <!--
                                        Grades for January - for testing purpose
                                      -->
                                      {% for grade in grades %}
                                        {% if grade.student.id == student.id and subject == grade.subject %}
                                          {{ grade.display_value }}
                                        {% endif %}
                                      {% endfor %}
                                    </td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>
                                      <div class="form-group grade-select">
                                        <select class="form-select" id="id_grade_{{student.id}}" name="grade_{{student.id}}">
                                          <option value="0" selected disabled hidden>Grade</option>
                                          <option value="1">1</option>
                                          <option value="1+">1+</option>
                                          <option value="2">2-</option>
                                          <option value="2">2</option>
                                          <option value="2+">2+</option>
                                          <option value="3-">3-</option>
                                          <option value="3">3</option>
                                          <option value="3+">3+</option>
                                          <option value="4-">4-</option>
                                          <option value="4">4</option>
                                          <option value="4+">4+</option>
                                          <option value="5-">5-</option>
                                          <option value="5">5</option>
                                          <option value="5+">5+</option>
                                          <option value="6-">6-</option>
                                          <option value="6">6</option>
                                        </select>
                                      </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                            {% endfor %}

                      </table>
                      <div class="form-group grade-select">
                        <select class="form-select" id="id_assigment" name="assigment">
                          <option value="0" selected disabled hidden>assigment</option>
                          {% for assigment in assigments %}
                            <option value="{{ assigment }}">{{ assigment }}</option>
                          {% endfor %}
                        </select>
                      </div>
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Add</button>
                    </form>
```

models.py

```
class Assigment(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    weight = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"

class Grade(models.Model):
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    assigment = models.ForeignKey(Assigment, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    value = models.FloatField()

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # convert values:
        CONVERTED_VALUES = {"-": 0, "1": 1, "1+": 1.25, "2-": 1.75, "2": 2, "2+": 2.25, "3-": 2.75, "3": 3, "3+": 3.25,
                             "4-": 3.75, "4": 4, "4+": 4.25, "5-": 4.75, "5": 5, "5+": 5.25, "6-": 5.75, "6": 6} 

        if type(self.value == str):
            self.value = CONVERTED_VALUES[self.value]
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def display_value(self):
        if self.value % 1 == 0.25:
            return f"{int(self.value)}+"
        elif self.value % 1 == 0.75:
            return f"{int(self.value) + 1}-"
        else:
            return f"{int(self.value)}"

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.student} - {self.assigment} - {self.value}"
```

and that's how my app looks like:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAdmV.png)

So i tried works with django formsets and inline_formsets but i had trouble with assigning my own names and id's as attribution and also assigning dynamic ammount of that "selects".

Thanks for help.

Comment: In that table form, you want to be able to add grades to all students on the same page?

Comment: Yes. In this select i have grades like 1,2,3,4,5,6 and in assigments something like "homework", "test". if i choose grade 3 for first student and grade 5 to second student and then assigment "homework" i want to add grades to all student with that one assigment.

Comment: Amd which grades are you displaying in the Month column?

Comment: Now i'm adding just for January for test purpose. For January in first row i have grades for first student and in second row i have for second student. But displaying works well i just cant figure out how can i change the "html" form to django form especially with sending lot of grades (for example to 15 student at once). I'm feeling that it can be something easy but i cant see that.

Comment: I see. That seems to be a good use case for `inlineformsets`. Do you still have the code you tried using inlineformset?